# eq() to select every 4th class

Tags: jquery

I want to use eq() to select every 4th item to add a class to zero the right margin. I got a mixed set of products which has a sub nav that toggles on and off products.

The nth() won't work because it counts all the products even when display:none and a specific class is selected.

Jquery

`$('li.prod').toggle(true);`

$('li.prod:visible:nth-child(4n)').addClass('prod-end');

$('li.button').click(function () {

```
$('li.button').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');

$('li.prod').removeClass('prod-end');

    if ( $('li#all').hasClass('active')) {

        $('li.prod').toggle(true);

        $('li.prod:visible:nth-child(4n)').addClass('prod-end');

    } else {

        $('li.prod').toggle(false);

        $('li.' + $(this).text()).toggle(true);

        $('li.' + $(this).text() + ':visible:nth-child(4n)').addClass('prod-end');

        }
```

});

```
HTML
```

```
    <div class="subNav">
            <ul>
              <li class="button active" id="all">all</li>
              <li class="button" id="men_apparel">men</li>
              <li class="button" id="women_apparel">women</li>
              <li class="button" id="kids">kids</li>
            </ul>
     </div>

<div class="products">
        <ul class="products_wrapper">

         <li class="prod women">      
</li>
<li class="prod women">      
</li>
<li class="prod women">      
</li>
<li class="prod women">      
</li>
<li class="prod men">      
</li>
<li class="prod men">      
</li>
<li class="prod men">      
</li>
<li class="prod kids">      
</li>
<li class="prod kids">      
</li>
<li class="prod kids">      
</li>
<li class="prod kids">      
</li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $('.products_wrapper li').each(function(){
        var i = $(this).index()+1;
        if (i%4==0) {
            $(this).addClass('prod-end');
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$('.foo:visible:nth-child(4)')
```

Comment: can you give details as to why not?

Comment: @Buildingbrick: "won't work" is such a bad comment. Please explain what didn't work, what didn't happen, what error message...

Comment: I did not investigate too much so I don't know other than it did not work so I moved on. Sorry I cannot provide more information.

Comment: It counts it even though its display:none. $('li.' + $(this).text() + ':visible:nth-child(4n)').addClass('prod-end');

Comment: if that's the case (seems odd), try:  `$('li:visible').filter(':nth-child(4)')`

Comment: No change. Its not recognizing the :visible...What about using eq() with a variable so it selects only the selected class and counts every 4th item. Example eq(3n) this doesn't work because I don't know how to add a variable correctly or if possible.

Comment: huh, you're right.  Digging into the jQuery source it's because it actually checks the # of previous children.  Submitting a jQuery bug.  In any case, you could accomplish this by: `$('li:visible').each(function(i, n){ i%4 || $(this).addClass('stripe'); })`

Comment: Actually, it's not a jQuery bug -- CSS selectors do exactly the same thing

Comment: The above works (selecting every 4th item) but it adding the first item too.

Comment: so adjust it :)  `(i-1)%4` will select every 4th starting at 3: 3, 7, 11, etc.  `i && (i%4 || $(this).ad...)` will select every 4th except 0: 4, 8, 12, etc.

Comment: :P wish I could. Don't understand this yet. Just bits and pieces. Whats the whole code for this...sorry thanks for the help!!

Comment: okay: `i%4` means "remainder of `i/4`", so `3/4 == 3`, `5/4 == 1`, `4/4 == 0`.  `||` in JavaScript only runs code that follows if the previous code is falsy.  Zero is falsy, so `i%4 || ...` only runs the code that follows if `i%4 == 0`, which is the case when i==0, 4, 8, etc...  `(i+1)%4` would then return `0` when i==3, 7, 11, etc...  The 2nd example uses `&&`, which only runs the stuff in parenthesis when `i` exists, thus ignoring everything in parens when `i == 0`

Comment: $('li.prod:visible').each(function(i, n){ i && i%4 || $(this).addClass('prod-end'); }) is this correct?

Comment: you need another set of parenthesis: `i && ( i%4...-end') );`

Comment: The first iteration is never the same? then it proceeds to the 4th...but it is only adding the class to the visible items :)

Comment: The first is the 5th because it's zero indexed.  "0, 4, 8" --> "1st, 5th, 9th".  Try `(i+1)%4`

Comment: Damn you are good! create another post with this answer and i;'ll give you cred. Also thanks for the explanation. Still a little fuzzy but I'll figure it out sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have to use `each` to deal with the fact that some can be hidden:

```
$("ul li:visible").each(function(i, el){
    if(i%4 === 3){
        $(this).addClass("prop_end");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RjbVV/2/

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$('li.prod:eq(4n)').addClass('prod-end');`

to

`$('li.prod:nth-child(4n)').addClass('prod-end');`

***fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KuMzp/***

---

Or is this what you mean?

***fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yuU9j/***

```
$('li.prod').toggle(true);

$('li.prod:nth-child(4n)').addClass('prod-end');

$('li.button').click(function() {
    $('li.button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('li.prod').removeClass('prod-end');
    if ($('li#all').hasClass('active')) {
        $('li.prod').toggle(true);
        $('li.prod:nth-child(4n)').addClass('prod-end');
    } else {
        $('li.prod').toggle(false);
        $('li.' + $(this).text()).toggle(true);
        $('li.' + $(this).text()).eq(3).addClass('prod-end');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't change my code back to its original state. Above is what I had originally. eq(3) will only count to the 4th item. I want it to addClass to every 4th item starting with the selected class of products.

Comment: True. but the code does add the class to every 4th item in the list. It's only when you click on 'women' for example that eq(3) is used.

Comment: I am really trying to stay away from the exceptions because I have many categories with different amount of product which all would need a special code. I just want to use one line for all.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/RjbVV/1/)

```
$("ul li:nth-child(4n)").addClass("prop-end");
```

Comment: Sorry the above code was not my original code. Now its correct. Yea this does work but when I toggle a product invisible it still is counted.